# Open Settings iOS 8 URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, uiapplication

How do we open Settings using the UIApplication.sharedApplication()

What URL should I pass in?

I used the `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` but it opens directly to the Application specific Settings page. but I would like to have it open the *first level* of the Settings app.

Or even better, I would like it to open directly to the page where user can enable the Location Services on their phone.

the codes below opens directly to the Application specific Settings page.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Settings programmatically like in Facebook app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer to this questions is **NO**, we can't open direct Location page ,but we can open `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` (settings page)

try this

```
if let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appSettings)
}
else
{
 // your URL is invalid
}
```

for additional [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503676/ios-8-swift-sending-user-directly-to-location-services-from-an-alert-dialog)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UIRequiresPersistentWiFi](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12) to `YES` in your `Info.plist` files and  create alertview like facebook the user launches your app without a network connection.

To summarize the discussion here:

**Step 1:** There is no URL you can use to get to the root level of the Settings app.

**Step 2:** You can send the user to your app's section of the Settings app using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` in iOS 8.

Your app can display the same alert as Facebook, which does open the root level of the Settings app, by setting `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

You can open settings apps programmatically try this(works only from iOS8 onwards).

If you are using `Swift`:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))
```

If you are using `Objective-C`

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

For other lower versions(less than iOS8) its not possible to programatically open settings app.

**Obj C:**

```
- (void)openSettings
{
    BOOL canOpenSettings = (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);

    if (canOpenSettings) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

**Swift:**

```
func openSettings() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Xamarin.iOS** developers:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString));
```